# Java Scanner FileReader

Tags: java

```
/* Выделяем числа
Считать с консоли 2 имени файла.
Вывести во второй файл все числа, которые есть в первом файле.
Числа выводить через пробел.
Закрыть потоки. Не использовать try-with-resources

Пример тела файла:
12 text var2 14 8v 1

Результат:
12 14 1
*/   
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fileLocation1 = bufReader.readLine();
            String fileLocation2 = bufReader.readLine();
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileLocation1);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileLocation2);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while(scanner.hasNext())
            {
                if(scanner.hasNextInt())
                {
                    int data = scanner.nextInt();
                    list.add(data);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                writer.write(list.get(i).toString() + ' ');
            }
            bufReader.close();
            scanner.close();
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        }
```

> //Не знаю, почему цикл while бесконечный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что внутри цикла while в случае, если не `Integer` Вы не читаете следующий элемент, т.е. не двигаетесь по файлу.

Добавьте к if

```
} else {
    scanner.next();
}
```